# Inserting variable into dynamic link with Classic asp

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm attempting to insert the text of a variable in a link generated with Classic ASP, but so far I'm striking out.  I'm trying to link to another page that includes the order ID as part of the link.  The link itself displays properly but strOID is not inserted into the link.

Is there a cleaner, more compact way to generate the link with the embedded variable?

**http://localhost/orderreview.asp?oid=/**

My code is:

```
<%
   Dim strOID

   if not rs.EOF then
        do

       strOID = rs("oid_num")         

       Response.Write "<tr><td width='12%'><a href='orderreview.asp?oid=' & strOID & ' onclick=showPopup(this.href);return(false);'>" & strOID
           Response.Write "</a></td>"
           rs.MoveNext

           if rs.EOF then exit do
        loop
     end if
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice the addition of the double-quotes...the first one terminates the first part of the string so that the `strOID` and remainder of the string can be concatenated.

```
Response.Write "<tr><td width='12%'><a href='orderreview.asp?oid='" & strOID & "' onclick=showPopup(this.href);return(false);'>" & strOID
```

Sorry, there isn't the convenience of [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation).

Comment: You've used single quotes for html attributes in your response.write statement.  If you want double quoted attributes you can achieve this by using double double quotes - eg `Response.Write "<tr><td width=""12%""><a href=""orderreview.asp?oid=" & strOID & """ onclick=""showPopup(this.href);return(false);"">" & strOID`

Answer (score 0):

User212514's method would work perfectly well.  An alternative would be to exit your asp scriptlet and start another one later, so you could simply code your repeaded region in HTML

This is probably easier to code if you're using an html editor with syntax highlighting - especially if your repeated region is more complex than a single table row.

Note that you can use the construction `<%= yourvariable %>` to insert an asp variable into your html.  the = sign is shorthand for Response.Write.

Using this method, your code would look like this

```
<%
   Dim strOID

   do while not rs.eof

       strOID = rs("oid_num")  
%>      
       <tr><td width="12%"><a href="orderreview.asp?oid=<%=strOID %>" onclick="showPopup(this.href);return(false);"><%=strOID %></a></td></tr>               
<%           
    rs.MoveNext              
    loop         
%>
```